# Peer error when trying composer network start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to start running my chaincode on a peer but when I do I get the following error in my peer logs:

> simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status
>   500 for txid

commands used:

```
mv ~/Downloads/creds_*_org2.json ./connection-profiles/${CHANNEL_NAME}/connection-profile-lessor.json
composer card create -f ca_Org2.card -p ./connection-profiles/${CHANNEL_NAME}/connection-profile-lessor.json -u admin -s ${LESSOR_SECRET}
composer card import -f ca_Org2.card -c ca_Org2
composer identity request --card ca_Org2 --path ./credentials/${CHANNEL_NAME}/lessor -u admin -s ${LESSOR_SECRET}

#Then sync reqeusted cert onto starter plan

composer card create -f adminCard_Org2-${CHANNEL_NAME}.card -p ./connection-profiles/${CHANNEL_NAME}/connection-profile-lessor.json -u admin -c ./credentials/${CHANNEL_NAME}/lessor/admin-pub.pem -k ./credentials/${CHANNEL_NAME}/lessor/admin-priv.pem --role PeerAdmin --role ChannelAdmin
composer card import -f adminCard_Org2-${CHANNEL_NAME}.card -c adminCardLessor-${CHANNEL_NAME}
composer network install -c adminCardLessor-${CHANNEL_NAME} -a ./contracts/blockaviation/dist/block-aviation-network.bna
composer network start -c adminCardLessor-defaultchannel -n block-aviation-network -V 0.0.1 -A admin -C ./credentials/defaultchannel/lessor/admin-pub.pem -f delete_me.card
```

This gives the folowing error in my terminal:

```
    composer network start -c adminCardLessor-defaultchannel -n block-aviation-network -V 0.0.1 -A admin -C ./credentials/defaultchannel/lessor/admin-pub.pem -f delete_me.card
Starting business network block-aviation-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: chaincode exists block-aviation-network)
Command failed
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

The above commands work for the first organisation in my network but fails with the above error for all other organisations.

If I do a ping with my card created for org1 I get the following result:

```
    composer network ping -c admin@block-aviation-network
The connection to the network was successfully tested: block-aviation-network
    Business network version: 0.0.1
    Composer runtime version: 0.19.5
    participant: org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin
    identity: org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#818307ea1e01cc0c691d856cc747e9a721e8424b420b73c0b2e4ce1ce406fbf3
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "composer": "^0.19.9"
  },
  "name": "block-aviation-network",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Smart aircraft leasing Business Network",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postlicchk": "npm run doc",
    "doc": "jsdoc --pedantic --recurse -c jsdoc.json",
    "test": "mocha -t 0 --recursive",
    "deployNetwork": "./deployNetwork.sh"
  },
  "author": "Simon Mullaney",
  "email": "simonpmullaney@gmail.com",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",
    "browserfs": "^1.2.0",
    "chai": "latest",
    "composer-admin": "^0.18.1",
    "composer-client": "^0.18.1",
    "composer-common": "^0.18.1",
    "composer-connector-embedded": "^0.18.1",
    "composer-playground-api": "^0.18.1",
    "composer-runtime": "^0.19.9",
    "composer-runtime-web": "^0.18.1",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "istanbul": "latest",
    "jsdoc": "latest",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "mocha": "latest",
    "moment": "latest",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "sinon": "latest"
  },
  "license-check-config": {
    "src": [
      "**/*.js",
      "!./coverage/**/*",
      "!./node_modules/**/*",
      "!./out/**/*",
      "!./scripts/**/*"
    ],
    "path": "header.txt",
    "blocking": true,
    "logInfo": false,
    "logError": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "es6-promise": "latest",
    "fabric-client": "^1.0.4",
    "grpc": "1.10.1",
    "opentracing": "^0.14.1",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "latest"
  }
}
```

I dont understand why it works for my first organisation but not for my other organisations?

EDIT:

I updated the chaincode on the network to version 0.0.2 - Now the package.json and the network have the same version of composer - 0.19.9

```
 composer network ping -c admin@block-aviation-network
The connection to the network was successfully tested: block-aviation-network
    Business network version: 0.0.2
    Composer runtime version: 0.19.9
    participant: org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin
    identity: org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#818307ea1e01cc0c691d856cc747e9a721e8424b420b73c0b2e4ce1ce406fbf3
```

The chaincode will still only run in the first organisation though - with all other orgs getting the same error as above.

If I follow on with commands to create a business network card to use on the business network for org2 I get the following:

```
composer card create -n block-aviation-network -p ./connection-profiles/${CHANNEL_NAME}/connection-profile-lessor.json -u lessor -c ./credentials/${CHANNEL_NAME}/lessor/admin-pub.pem -k ./credentials/${CHANNEL_NAME}/lessor/admin-priv.pem
composer card import -f ./lessor@block-aviation-network.card
composer network ping -c lessor@block-aviation-network
```

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: could not get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for block-aviation-network:0.0.2: get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for block-aviation-network/defaultchannel from LSCC error: chaincode fingerprint mismatch data mismatch
>   Command failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this in IBM Starter Plan, but based on the Composer [Multi Org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) you Install the network once per Organisation, but you only Start the network once per Network, and you supply Admin Certificates from both Organisations on the `composer network start` command.

So I think what you are seeing is that the Network is already running for Org 2, but the Admin for Org 2 does not have access as it was not specified on the start command line.

Comment: I think you could be right - Thank you so much R Thatcher! I will let you know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do "**composer network install**" on all the peers of the network . And then a single "**composer network start**" command .

If that doesn't upgrade the network - try using "**composer network upgrade**" command . Should work.